# How to get data of last 24 hours on top in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord

There is a model `post` . Post are created by either PM or User. I want to get all posts in which the posts created by PM in last 24 hours come on top.

I try

```
posts.sort_by{|t| -t["role_id"] }
```

But by this PM all posts on top. I want PM posts of only last 24 hours on top.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:
`Post.where('created_at > ?', 24.hours.ago).order(role_id: :asc)`

Comment: I want to get all posts in which the posts created by PM in last 24 hours come on top

Comment: `posts.sort_by{|t| t.created_at < 24.hours.ago? ? -t["role_id"] : t.id }`

Comment: I don't fully understand your logic requirements, but you can use any conditions in the `sort_by` block to achieve what you want.

Comment: `t.role_id == PM_ID && t.created_at <= 24.hours.ago? ? 1_000_000_000 : t.id`

Comment: However, I'd recommend combining two queries instead: `Post.where('created_at > ?', 24.hours.ago).where(role_id: PM_ID)` and `Post.where('created_at <= ?', 24.hours.ago).or.where.not(role_id: PM_ID)`

Comment: basically I want PM post which is created in last 24 hours on top of page and remaining posts in after that

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  This will select ONLY posts created in the last 24 hours.  I think he wants posts created in the last 24 hours which were also created by PM at the top, and all others to follow.

Answer (score 1):

To confirm your question, you want ALL records and the sort to be:

1. Records created by pm && within last 24 hours (internally sorted by something else)
2. followed by all other records sorted by something else.

I would create a synthetic boolean sort field like this:

```
time = 24.hours.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %M:%S")
Post.order("(created_at < '#{time}' && cont_term = 24) ASC")
```

It will resolve to 0 or 1 so you can sort by this field first and add additional order() clauses to sort within those groups.